# PHP - HMAC Authentication

Tags: php, api, hmac

I'm getting that error code (I'm using a public API so it's certainly working on their side ;)):

> HMAC authentication key and signature was given, but they are invalid.

```
function get_myself($request){
    $public_key = "MY_PUBLIC_KEY";
    $secret = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";

    $parameters = array(
        "client_id" => $public_key,
        "client_secret" => $secret
    );
    $data = http_build_query($parameters);

    $ch = curl_init("https://localbitcoins.com".$request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $nonce = time();
    $sig = base64_encode ( hash_hmac("sha256", $nonce.$public_key.$request, $secret ) );
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER =>   array(
            "Apiauth-Key:".$public_key,
            "Apiauth-Nonce:".$nonce,
            "Apiauth-Signature:".$sig
        ),
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$getinfo = array();
$getinfo = get_myself("/api/myself/");
echo "<pre>"; print_r($getinfo); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: https://localbitcoins.com/api-docs/errors/ says that you should "Ensure validity of key, secret and signature calculation."

Comment: I have but credentials are ok that's not where the problem comes from... Just in case someone else has that issue I've found online another code that is working... I'll post it bellow ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 3 days, I found the 'solution'... here's a working example:

```
function localbitcoins_query($path, array $req = Array()) {
   $key='MY_KEY';
   $secret='MY_SECRET';
   $mt = explode(' ', microtime());
   $nonce = $mt[1].substr($mt[0], 2, 6);
   if ($req) {
      $get=httpbuildquery($req);
      $path=$path.'?'.$get;
   }
   $postdata=$nonce.$key.$path;
   $sign = strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $postdata, $secret));
   $headers = array(
      'Apiauth-Signature:'.$sign,
      'Apiauth-Key:'.$key,
      'Apiauth-Nonce:'.$nonce
   );
   $ch = null;
   $ch = curl_init('https://localbitcoins.com'.$path);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
   $res = curl_exec($ch);
   if ($res === false) throw new Exception('Curl error: '.curlerror($ch));
   $dec = json_decode($res, true);
   if (!$dec) throw new Exception('Invalid data: '.$res);
   curl_close($ch);
   return $dec;
}

$getinfo = array();
$devise = "EUR";
$url = "/buy-bitcoins-online/".$devise."/western-union/.json";

$getinfo = localbitcoins_query($url);   
echo "<pre>"; print_r($getinfo); echo "</pre>";
```

It's working on my side, I suppose the POST / GET notion wasn't previously handle properly whereas it is in that version.

Enjoy :p

Comment: don't forget that you can approve your own answer

Comment: why not use microtime(true) ? will return a float instead of string